# How to return a dynamic arrays of pointers from a method

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, function, pointers, dynamic-arrays

Please have look at the following code

**VehicleManager.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Vehicle.h"

class VehicleManager
{
public:
    VehicleManager(int size);
    ~VehicleManager(void);

    bool add(Vehicle *v);
    void display();
    int getCount();
    Vehicle **getList();

private:
    int count;
    int maxVehicles;
    Vehicle** vehicles;
};
```

**VehicleManager.cpp**

```
//Other Code

Vehicle VehicleManager::**getList()
{
    return vehicles;
}

//Other Code
```

In here, I am unable to return the array. How can I return a dynamic arrays of pointer from a function? Please help!

Comment: `::` is the scope resolution operator. `**` needs no scope resolution. I'd highly recommend looking into a vector of smart pointers if you're sure you do need a dynamic array of pointers, though.

Comment: I am also agree with the Vector suggestion, and I know this is a stupid way :( . But what to do, it is given in writing to follow the steps :(

Comment: Why do you need to get the vehicles? Tell the vehicle manager what to do with them. I assume that's what `display` does. Add other functions to do whatever else you need to do, e.g. `updateTime`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the `**` to the return type:

```
Vehicle** VehicleManager::getList()
{
    return vehicles;
}
```

But what you should really do is use an `std::vector<Vehicle*>` if the `VehicleManager` is in charge of the lifetime of the dynamicallly allocated `Vehicles` , or an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Vehicle>` if the caller is to take ownership. In both cases you can return it by value.

Comment: Thanks :) Much appreciated. I am also agree with the Vector suggestion, and I know this is a stupid way :( . But what to do, it is given in writing to follow the steps :(

Comment: @Sepala just as long as you don't use that `**` stuff in real code... I think too much time is spent learning C techniques that you then have to unlearn. Some never get the time to unlearn, resulting in code that is hard to maintain and use.